# Datagridview updation bug

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my my project, I wrote a code such that if there is no data in the DGV it should not be updated, but even though data is not there when I click on the row which is empty and comes by default, and then on update button, it is getting updated. Please help me to fix the issue. The code I am using is:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView2.SelectedCells.Count == 0 )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are no any records to update");
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection con = Helper.getconnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        string PrjName = txtPrjNmae.Text;
        string Description = txtPrjdescription.Text;
        DateTime Date = dateUpdate.Value;
        dateUpdate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateUpdate.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
        string Size = txtPrjSize.Text;
        string Manager = txtPrjManager.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Update Projects set Description='" + Description + "', DateStarted='" + Date + "',TeamSize='" + Size + "',Manager='" + Manager + "' where ProjectName= '" + PrjName + "' ";
        MessageBox.Show("Project Details are updated");
        dataGridView2.Update();
        dataGridView2.Refresh();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    BindData3();            
}
```

Comment: I am having a doubt that I should some other condition instead of: if(dataGridView2.SelectedCells.Count == 0 ). But I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: how do you allow users to add new row ? using new form ? or by editing DGV ?

Comment: I am sorry for causing confusion, the data is enetered through other form and the data to DGV is binded from the database. My actual requirement is when I click on the update button button, I am getting messages from message box.show() as updated, but if there there any value in the DGV and even though row is clicked and then on update I should get message as ("There are no any records to update"). I sincerely apologize.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent user from adding new row by click on the last row of `datagridview` via settig `AllowUserToAddRows = false`

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0
```

in a condition

Comment: If AllowUserToAddRows is set to true row count will not be zero.

Comment: i agreed but i think he wants to add...,

Answer (score 0):

first set

```
dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false
```

or

check every time while updating.

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0
```

or

```
if(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() != " ")
```

//do ur update here

Comment: If users are allowed to insert new row through datagridview AllowUserToAddRows can't be set to false and keeping it true will always have a empty row so row count will be at least 1

Comment: then check for first row (or) cell is empty  or not,and rows count also with && condition.

Comment: I am sorry for causing confusion, the data is enetered through other form and the data to DGV is binded from the database. My actual requirement is when I click on the update button button, I am getting messages from message box.show() as updated, but if there there any value in the DGV and even though row is clicked and then on update I should get message as ("There are no any records to update"). I sincerely apologize. Issue is same even after using if( dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0) { } Thank you

Comment: Is it sure the data will updating in database also?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `if (dataGridView2.SelectedCells.Count == 0 )`

Do this

if( dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0)
{

}

This will only do conditions if there is more than 0 rows.

Comment: I am sorry for causing confusion, the data is enetered through other form and the data to DGV is binded from the database. My actual requirement is when I click on the update button button, I am getting messages from message box.show() as updated, but if there there any value in the DGV and even though row is clicked and then on update I should get message as ("There are no any records to update"). I sincerely apologize. Issue is same even after using if( dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0) {

}
 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are letting the users to insert row through a different form (*not through grdiview*) first `hide` the empty row which is displayed by default as `AllowUserToAddRow` property is set to `true`, You have to set this property to `false`.

Still if you are allowing the users to add empty row to the grid in some other way then you have to validate it when user click update button. One approach i could think of is,

Check if the selected row has one of the `mandatory cell value`. Assume ProjectName is mandatory value then you can write a logic as follows,

`selectedRow.Cells["ProjectName"]` here ProjectName is column name.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Get the selected row
       DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];

       //Check if Project Name cell in the selected row null or empty
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedRow.Cells["ProjectName"].Value.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no any records to update");
        }
        else
        {

        }                      
    }
```